# Eloquent Javascript version 1 chapter 7 shortest path

Tags: javascript, search, recursion, shortest-path

The solution to [the shortest path problem in EJS version 1](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter7.html):

```
function possibleRoutes(from, to) {
  function findRoutes(route) {
    function notVisited(road) {
      return !member(route.places, road.to);
    }
    function continueRoute(road) {
      return findRoutes({places: route.places.concat([road.to]),
                         length: route.length + road.distance});
    }

    var end = route.places[route.places.length - 1];
    if (end == to)
      return [route];
    else
      return flatten(map(continueRoute, filter(notVisited,
                                               roadsFrom(end))));
  }
  return findRoutes({places: [from], length: 0});
}
```

The solution finds every possible path from `from` to `to`. The `findRoutes` function recurses and for every successful path: `if(end == to) return [route]`. The final output is an array of `route` objects.

Where is this array of route objects coming from if we are only returning a single route object? Why don't we have to declare `var routes = []; routes.push([route]);`. How does the program know to output the route objects in one big array?

Comment: Quote from the doc you linked to: "Another function we will need is `flatten`. This function takes an array of arrays, and puts the elements of the arrays together in one big array."

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did see that. But, doesn't the code either `return [route]` OR `return flatten(....)` if `end != to`?

Comment: `findRoutes` does, yes. I don't follow the question.

Comment: `findRoutes` recurses and every time a path is found that meets `end == to` it returns `[route]`. How is the final output an array of every route when all we return is a single object without pushing that object to a larger array? I see `flatten()` but I don't see how it is connected to pushing the route object into the final array.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I get it now. I shouldn't ask questions at 3am... Thanks for your help.